# Connect ssas to grafana => use a created and deployed cube on ssas in grafana

Tags: plugins, ssas, grafana, olap-cube

I created a **olap cube** using **ssas** (SQL Server Analysis Services) , then, i **deployed it**.
I want to **display the cube data in grafana**.
Any help please ?

I checked that it's not feasable to connect ssas to grafana directly.
then i tried to find plugins or middlewares but in vain.